# I have written a code to convert from Celisius to Fahrenheit but the output is too huge

Tags: c, double, format-specifiers, conversion-specifier

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    double C, F;
    printf("Enter the temperature in Celisius: ");
    scanf("%f", &C);
    F = 32 + (C * (180.0 / 100.0));
    printf("%f C = %f F\n", C, F);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> Enter the temperature in Celisius: 100
>   -92559604910177974000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 C =
>   -166607288838320360000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 F

Comment: You are using the wrong format specifier. `double`s are printed with `%lf`

Comment: @StoryTeller is it? :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - C99 allowed it, I assume so that calls to printf and scanf will match, so one really ought to use it.

Comment: @StoryTeller for `printf()` family, `l` length modifier has no effect on `f` conversion specifier.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - [That change is explicitly mentioned in the revision to the second edition](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp7). And again, this is for consistency. Using different format specifiers contributes to precisely this type of mistakes.

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debug info (i.e. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), then improve your code to get no warnings, then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and repeat till you are happy with your code.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's true, but allowing the length modifier there does not make that a requirement, does it? It is perfectly valid (and I'd say, expected) to use `%f` for `doubles`. Well, APIs got their requirements, inn'it? :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - I'd disagree. All other format specifiers for printf and scanf match. This mismatch is poor design. It's "allowed" because it cannot be "required' (argument promotion and all that). But it most certainly should be required in code review.

Comment: BTW, you misspelt "[Celsius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got wrong conversion specifier there with `double` for `scanf()`. You need to use

```
  scanf("%lf", &C);
```

To add the relevant quote, from `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2

> `l` (ell)
>
> Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, or `n` conversion specifier applies
>   to an argument with type pointer to `long int` or `unsigned long
>   int`; that a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier applies to
>   an argument with type pointer to `double`; or that a following `c`, `s`, or `[`
>   conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `wchar_t`.

That said, you must check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure the success of the call. Otherwise, you'll end up using the value of an uninitialized variable.